# Get text and form data from and html table and use it for a servlet

Tags: java, html, parsing, servlets, html-table

It there a simple way to read text from an html table using Java. I want to use that data from the table to create objects and store in a database.  The table has three columns, two have text and one is a form that the user can use to input data. I would like to read everything in the table and store it in an object, are there any Java libraries that allow this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to download an existing HTML page and parse that, or do you want to submit the form to the servlet and let the servlet gather the submitted data? That are two *completely* different requirements.

Comment: Based on your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436436/using-htmlunit-on-a-webpage-generated-by-a-servlet) you seen to want the former. This is completely unrelated to servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpUnit.

http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook.html