# Using HTMLUnit on a webpage generated by a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, htmlunit

How could I use HTMLUnit to get data from a webpage generated by a java servlet. I keep getting an error when I try to read the webpage. /getSurvey is the servlet that creates the webpage but how can I access the HTML generated from the servlet.

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://survey-creator.appspot.com/getSurvey");

Comment: And the error you get is ... ?

Comment: The fact that the page is generated by the servlet is meaningless for HtmlUnit. It's a programmatic web browser accessing web resources like any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit is not really "just" a HTML parser. It's kind of a programmatic webbrowser. It's intented to surf through web pages and/or fill out web forms programmatically using Java language. If your sole purpose is to get the HTML as a String, use a real HTML parser. I can recommend [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for this.

```
String html = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com").get().html();
```

That's it. It can however do much more than that, such as [selecting elements of interest](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

#### See also:

- [Pros and cons of leading HTML parsers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)